# How do I count objects available in a Salesforce organization?

Tags: custom-object, object

I need to count the total number of custom objects available in a Salesforce 
organization. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily do this using Global Describe

```
map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
for (Schema.SObjectType Obj : GlobalMap.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ObjDesc = Obj.getDescribe();
    system.debug('Object Name: ' + ObjDesc.getName());
}
System.debug(GlobalMap.size() );
```

Or if you want to see only custom objects then

```
Integer count = 0;
map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
    for (Schema.SObjectType Obj : GlobalMap.values()) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ObjDesc = Obj.getDescribe();
        if(ObjDesc.iscustom()){
           count ++;
           system.debug('Object Name: ' + ObjDesc.getName());
        }
    }
System.debug('Custom Object '+ count );
```

Comment: can we display count value in visual force page also?

Comment: @ookkk yes sure. Declare a public integer variable and then display it in VF page.

Comment: thanks tushar..i need custom objects only and I  can see custom settings also.